Cache Busting in Flutter Web for New Releases: Issues with Clearing Old Cache
I'm developing a Flutter Web project, and I’m encountering issues with cache busting after deploying new releases. Despite trying multiple solutions, older versions of files (e.g., main.dart.js) seem to persist, causing users to load outdated files instead of the latest release. is there a specific way it should be done with flutter web?
Steps I've Tried:
File Versioning:
I appended version numbers to the names of files, such as:
<script src="main.dart.js?v=1.0.57.39d6d65"></script>.
However, this didn’t seem to resolve the issue for all users.
Service Worker Cache Management:
I added a version to the cache name variable in the service worker and updated it during releases to delete the old cache.
Unfortunately, this approach didn’t consistently work either.
html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <title>My Flutter Web App</title>

    <script>
      const serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    </script>
    <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
    <script src="main.dart.js?v=1.0.57.39d6d65"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
        _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
          serviceWorker: {
            serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
          },
          onEntrypointLoaded: function (engineInitializer) {
            engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function (appRunner) {
              appRunner.runApp();
            });
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



I mean... cachebusting always works. the browser can't load a resource it hasn't cached from cache.
